# CSS image float:left?

Tags: css, image, css-float

I want create a basic slider with css and jquery. I add 4 images to page in img tags. But I can't show these images side by side. I don't know where is the error. I give codes. Now only I want to show images side by side but I can't.

*deneme.html*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sliderStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car1.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car2.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car3.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car4.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*sliderStyle.css*

```
*{ padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; border:0; text-decoration:none; } 
    .slider{
        font-size:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .slider ul{
        float:left;
    }

    img {
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your question ... [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/bkvk1mab/) an example of how you can show pictures. Why do you use many tags ?

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    border:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.slider {
    font-size:0;
    display:left;
}
ul {
    display: block;
}
img {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sliderB img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: firstly thanks for your comment. I did exactly what is written in your example. Only I changed image name but it doesn't work correctly. Images didn't look like the sliderB.

Comment: Actually I want to do this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ch0ym85YdRs (04.43). But although I write the same code, did not give the same result. I dont understand reason

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

HTML (I removed som tags taht were unnecessary):

```
<div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car1.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car2.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car3.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="car4.jpg" alt="" class="img"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{ padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; border:0; text-decoration:none; } 

.slider li{
    float:left;
}

.slider ul{
    width: /* -- the sum of your images width -- */;
    /* -- or use the jquery script below to calculate it -- */
}
```

JQUERY (this calculate the sum of the images width in the slider):

```
var totalwidth = 0;
$(".slider img").each(function(){
    totalwidth += $(this).width();
});
$(".slider ul").css("width",totalwidth);
```

It should be easy to make the slider now. Hope it helps!

Comment: If the HTML file you shared is the complete one, you forgot to reference the jQuery library.
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`
or you can download it here : https://jquery.com/download/